# How to populate a list/dictionary with item counts?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Working on a Function that counts similar items in a DataFrame column. Below is what I have so far, but it's not working correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
brands = {'BAI': 0, 'SMARTWATER': 0, 'SPARKLING ICE': 0, 'ZICO': 0, 'IZZE': 0, 'VITA COCO': 0,
     'PERRIER': 0, 'C20': 0, 'HIBALL ENERGY': 0, 'TASTE NIRVANA': 0}

for row in df:
    c_rating = df['Brand']
    if c_rating in brands:
        brands[c_rating] += 1
    else:
        brands[c_rating] = 1
print(brands)
```

I get the following error, "TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed," but I'm not sure how to go about fixing the function. Would I have to append brands to the dictionary instead of +=?

Comment: could you post the `df` sample dataset.

Comment: From the looks of it you can simply do `from collections import Counter; print (Counter(df['Brand']))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `value_counts`

```
df['Brand'].value_counts().to_dict()
```